# Stateless function with TypeScript error in React: TS2352 cannot be converted to type 'Promise<StatelessComponent<{}>>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise

I'm new to TypeScript and having following codes.

```
import * as React from 'react';
const Product: React.SFC<{}> = () => <div>Product</div>;
export default Product;
```

---

```
import { asyncComponent } from 'react-async-component';

const AsyncProduct = asyncComponent({
  name: 'AsyncProduct',
  serverMode: 'resolve',
  resolve: () => {
    return import(/* webpackChunkName: "Product" */ './Product') as Promise<React.SFC<{}>>;
  },
});

export default AsyncProduct;
```

> ./src/AsyncProduct.tsx (7,12): error TS2352: Type 'Promise'
>   cannot be converted to type 'Promise>'.   Type
>   'typeof
>   "/Users/banyan/tmp/typescript-react-async-component-example/src/Product"'
>   is not comparable to type 'StatelessComponent<{}>'.
>       Type 'typeof "/Users/banyan/tmp/typescript-react-async-component-example/src/Product"'
>   provides no match for the signature '(props: { children?: ReactNode;
>   }, context?: any): ReactElement | null'.

If I change the `Promise<React.SFC<{}>` to be `Promise<any>`, it can be compiled, but how can I specify the stateless function?

This is the minimum repo to reproduce with `yarn start`: https://github.com/banyan/typescript-react-async-component-example

---

The definition of type is like this: `node_modules/react-async-component/index.d.ts`.

```
/**
 * The configuration for an asynchronous component.
 */
export interface Configuration<P> {
    resolve: () => Promise<React.ComponentType<P>>;
...
}
```

Comment: Your render function maybe needs to take the react arguments even if you aren't using them ?

onst Product: React.SFC<{}> = (props: { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any) => <div>Product</div>;

But i'm just guessing. i'm not super awesome at React yet. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `import` function returns the whole module, you have to the select what exactly you want to use from the module (the default export or a named one):

Using `async/await` :

```
const AsyncProduct = asyncComponent({
  name: 'AsyncProduct',
  serverMode: 'resolve',
  resolve: async () => {
    var module = await import('./Product');
    return module.default;
  },
});
```

Or with then:

```
const AsyncProduct2 = asyncComponent({
  name: 'AsyncProduct',
  serverMode: 'resolve',
  resolve: () => {
    return import('./Product').then(m=> m.default);
  },
});
```